# Why this code can access the dictionary without ""?

Tags: python

In Python, by typing `digit_mapping.get("1")`, I can access value of one in this dictionary. I am wondering why it still can access the dictionary without `""` around the character inside the get method in this code.

like `output += digit_mapping.get("character", "!") + " "`

```
phone = input("Phone: ")
digit_mapping = {
    "1": "One",
    "2": "Two",
    "3": "Three",
    "4": "Four"
}
output = ""
for character in phone:
    output += digit_mapping.get(character, "!") + " "
print(output)
```

Comment: `character` is a variable, why does it need quotes?

Comment: `"character"` would be literally the string "character". `character` is a variable, and if it holds a string, then it's already a string, which you don't need to put into quotes again.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `character` is a variable. It holds a value; in your case, a `string`. `"character"`, on the other hand, is a `string`. In your example, `"character"` would return nothing, since the dictionary doesn't carry a key by that name. On the other hand, the value that the variable `character` contains (`"1", "2", "3" and "4"`; a value for each iteration within the `for`-loop) is a valid `key` in the dictionary and would yield the desired `value` from the dictionary.